# sym link parent dirs

Tags: linux, symlink

`ln` basic question from a beginner:

I have some legacy code that looks for a series of files at a location

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/
```

for example

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/abc.xml
```

the files are really at a location

```
/z/w/v/d/e/f/g/h/i/
```

I tried to link `/z/w/v` to `/a/b/c` like

```
mkdir /a/b/c
ln -s /z/w/v /a/b/c
```

but when I `cd /a/b/c` I end up one level higher.
Is it possible to `ln` the parent dirs like this or I just have to link the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the directory `/a/b/c` already exists, because of the `mkdir`. So when you make the link, it thinks you want to make a link *in* the `c`, not from `c` itself. So it's as if you did:

```
ln -s /z/w/v /a/b/c/v
```

Do it like this:

```
mkdir /a/b
ln -s /z/w/v /a/b/c
```